# Nvidia drivers question

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04

I have a question about drivers, should I use the ones, provided by ubuntu(14.04 - 331.38), or should I install the latest ones from nvidia(331.79)? which would work better? Nvidia page says this:

> Note that many Linux distributions provide their own packages of the
>   NVIDIA Linux Graphics Driver in the distribution's native package
>   management format. This may interact better with the rest of your
>   distribution's framework, and you may want to use this rather than
>   NVIDIA's official package.

So, I'm kind of scared to try that since I had bad experience with installing the latest AMD Radeon drivers before. I know, it's not the same but still...

And if I should choose 331.38 which one of that?
[image]
331.38 - updates what difference is between this and 331.38

Thanks!

Comment: I would stick with the first option that you have highlighted there, if you're worried about performance. Using nouveau (the last option) is nice because it's open source, but it does have performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me that the 1st choice which is a stable proprietary -tested to be stable is what i would choose.

to check what your graphics card is using Nvidia.
Type or copy and paste this in terminal

```
sudo lshw -c display
```

** If it is saying other than Nvidia.Type: Intell, Amd or Ati Radeon. Do not change anything since if hardware is not using Nvidia drivers then you do not need to change it to do so.

to make sure that you have latest stable version if your graphics card is using Nvidia. Open terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T

You can also use the stable PPA, if you want to stay updated with your drivers:

Open a terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

to know what graphics card you are using. If `sudo lshw -c display`
did not list it. You can try to list it by this command in terminal.

```
lspci -kif
```

Look where it say's VGA compatible controller: 'if it listing Nvidia here '
then you can choose the first option with out having any fears.

I will list here a site where you can find latest Nvidia drivers and how to install them to your Ubuntu.

http://www.sysads.co.uk/?s=Nvidia

They should work all to get your system use the best performance on Nvidia.

If you run in to other types or troubles or questions about Nvidia what i can think of is,make sure that you have the latest stable version of the kernel module installed always when wanting to upgrade Nvidia or graphics drivers.

Comment: Thank you so much!! this helped a lot!!!  I had some issues with animation settings in compiz for example "windows focus" animation particularly - Dodge animation effect, it didn't work properly, windows became black all the time, after installing drivers by using your commands it works perfectly!!

Comment: I am glad that you got it working. /Eimis